# Upload a file and get word cloud in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, word-cloud

My Shiny App will not display the word cloud after the file upload. There is no error message and the page just doesn't have any reaction. I have basically copied and pasted the code on Shiny App Gallery, but I don't know what is wrong. I think the problem might be because the server didn't read the file correctly from the `fileInput` function. I have modified the `readline` part. Most of UI and server functions are here.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/word-cloud.html

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

Please help.

```
getTermMatrix <- memoise(function(df) {

  myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(df$x))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords,
                    pattern)

  myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,
                             control = list(minWordLength = 1))

  m = as.matrix(myDTM)

  sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
})
```

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Wordcloud Generating Tool"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                ),
                placeholder = "No file selected"
      ),
      actionButton("update", "Get the Word Cloud"),
      sliderInput("freq",
                  "Minimum Frequency:",
                  min = 1,  max = 50, value = 15),
      sliderInput("max",
                  "Maximum Number of Words:",
                  min = 1,  max = 300,  value = 100)),
    mainPanel(
      texttOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {


  terms <- reactive({

    terms <- reactive({
      # Change when the "update" button is pressed...
      input$update
      # ...but not for anything else
      isolate({
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
          getTermMatrix(df)
        })
      })
    })

    # Make the wordcloud drawing predictable during a session
    wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      v <- terms()
      wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
                    min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
                    colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: Can you share your `inFile` and make a whole/reproducible shiny-app out of your example?

Comment: I tried to just let the app read the file and display the head(), but that doesn't work. My files usually only have two columns. X and x. I want to make a word cloud out of the `x` column.